# Proving that a punctured disk is not simply connected, using a specific definition

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, alternative-proof

I am dealing with the same set based on my previous question. I want to show that the set $H = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : 0 < |z| < 1\}$ is NOT simply connected, using the following definitions, that our teacher insists upon us using:

*A region $G$ is simply connected iff $\mathbb{C}^{\infty} \setminus G$, its complement in the extended plane, is connected in $\mathbb{C}^{\infty}$.*

*A set $H$ is not connected if $\exists$ open sets $U$ and $V$ such that $$U \cap H \neq \varnothing, V \cap H \neq \varnothing, \ H \subseteq U \cup V, \ \mathrm{and} \ U \cap V = \varnothing.$$*

If I can show that the set $\mathbb{C}^{\infty} \setminus H$ is not connected in $\mathbb{C}^{\infty}$, then I will have that $H$ is not simply connected.

But how can I come up with sets $U,V$?

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Still, link to the pervious question.

Comment: The complement of your set is $\{0\} \cup \{z \in \Bbb C^\infty : 1 \leq |z|\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the punctured disk is punctured, in that it does not contain $0$. Further, you can enclose $0$ in a small open ball $B$, and $\{ z:|z| \geq 1 \}$ in the complement of a closed ball. Calling this ball $C$, we need it to be such that $B \cap C^{\complement} = \emptyset$. The complement of $H$, which is $ \{ 0\} \cup \{ z: |z| \geqslant 1 \} $, is contained in these two disjoint open sets.

Comment: @arabhimanachra Couple of typos. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks. What is an example of such a closed ball $C$? I am not able to think of one!

Comment: Well, you can take something like $\{ z : |z| \leqslant 9/10 \}$, for example. That gives you plenty of room if you use $\{ z_S: |z| < 1/10 \}$ to cover $\{0\}$.

Comment: In that case... $B \cap C^{\complement} = \varnothing,$ not $B \cap C = \varnothing$, as in your answer.

Comment: Hm. Bracketing error. Made it unambiguous.

Comment: I really understand now.